# Spring global method security and rememberMe not working together

Tags: spring, spring-security, jsr250

I also have two separate paths to secure so each one has its own config.

My config: (the same for path-a & path-b)

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, jsr250Enabled = true)
@Order(2)
public class CandidateConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .antMatcher("/path-a/**").authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/",  LANDING_PAGE, "/path-a/login").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/path-a/**").hasRole(ROLE-A)
                .and().formLogin().loginPage("/path-a/login").permitAll()
                .and().logout().permitAll()
                .and().rememberMe()
                .and().csrf().disable();
```

I also have global method security enabled, and methods that are not on "path-a"or "path-b" are annotated with @RolesAllowed("ROLE-A")
the security part works well - only when authenticated will the methods work.

The only problem is that when the path is not identified - the spring security filters are not running , only the method security interceptor is.
When there is no authentication - the RememberMe filter did not run to check the cookie and now I get access denied.

How can I make the global method security paths to run the remember me filter?

Comment: Did You try andMatchers(/*).rememberMe() ?

Comment: I did not put all my config , just put a simplistic view for the problem, but maybe I should have. I have a different rememberMe config for each path, so where would I put the (/*) ?

Comment: I ended up adding all the paths to the config instead of relying on global method security.